# Does Heine-Borel Theorem hold in $\prod_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}$, where $A$ is any index set?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Does Heine-Borel Theorem hold in $\prod_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}$, where $A$ is any set? That is is, every closed and bounded set compact in $\prod_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}$?

In finite case this is true. I am not sure about infinite product.

Comment: What is *bounded* in your product set?

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard notion of "bounded" for a subset of $\mathbb{C}^A$ in general.  When $A$ is finite then all norms on $\mathbb{C}^A$ are equivalent and give a canonical notion of boundedness, but this all breaks down if $A$ is infinite.  Indeed, if $A$ is uncountable, then $\mathbb{C}^A$ is not even metrizable (in the product topology).

However, if you take "bounded" to mean "bounded on each coordinate separately", then the answer is yes.  That is, suppose $S\subseteq\mathbb{C}^A$ is a closed set such that for each $a\in A$, the set $\{f(a):f\in S\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is bounded.  Then $S$ is compact.  This follows from Tychonoff's theorem: any product of compact spaces is compact.  So, letting $B_a$ be a closed ball containing $\{f(a):f\in S\}$, the product $\prod_{a\in A}B_a$ is compact and $S$ is a closed subset of it, and so $S$ is also compact.

Comment: To the proposer: Tychonoff's theorem (a.k.a. the Tychonoff Theorem) is not something I would call  obvious.